# Would it be possible for Russia to "unannex" parts of Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, territory, territorial-dispute

How easy is it now for Russia to undo their annexation of the parts of Ukraine that they recently took or at least laid claim to? e.g. if there was a change of leadership to someone not in favour of the war, or if the war doesn't go well for Russia?

I mean within Russia's own political and legal framework.

Could it be simply swept under the carpet and kind of ignored, or would allowing Ukraine to have it back be akin to signing away a piece of Russia, like say, Belgorod Oblast? Are Russia now forever forced to maintain their claim on the territory and defend it and attempt to retake it with the same zeal they would if say a foreign army were attempting to occupy Russia itself?

Comment: Remark: there is a tendency to overestimate the importance of *peace treaties* and other *legal steps*, as opposed to the facts on the ground (like ceasefire/truce/cessation of hostilities). One could envisage a situation where Ukraine regains full control of its territory and this is acknowledged by Russia, without formalizing it as a peace agreement. Situations like this may last for decades - consider, e.g., the absence of a peace treaty between Russia and Japan, the status of Taiwan, etc.

Comment: @RogerVadim that could probably make a fairly good answer

Comment: @RogerVadim One might also mention the UK and the Republic of Ireland: the two states were on pretty friendly terms in the 1980s and 1990s, despite having competing territorial claims.  (Some relevant non-state actors, of course, were on very unfriendly terms indeed.)

Comment: @RogerVadim You'd also get my vote for a good answer on that premise.  Absent sanction lifting considerations it seems a more likely outcome than the trauma of permanent constitutional changes to un-protect Russian territories as part of a formal peace treaty IF that is the only way out.

Comment: This question is part of a calculated disinformation campaign of Russia. Hungarian opposition media has just covered it today: https://444.hu/2022/10/08/racz-andras-moszkva-elhitetne-hogy-az-annexiok-utan-nincs-visszaut-ukrajna-es-a-nyugat-lehivja-az-orosz-bloffot

Comment: In the article **“Moscow would have you believe that there is no way back after the annexations, Ukraine and the West calls Russia's bluff”** Hungarian opposition media covered this under the Google translate link below:

https://444-hu.translate.goog/2022/10/08/racz-andras-moszkva-elhitetne-hogy-az-annexiok-utan-nincs-visszaut-ukrajna-es-a-nyugat-lehivja-az-orosz-bloffot?_x_tr_sl=hu&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

**I invite others to flag and vote to close.**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acording to [article 67](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_28399/8c6502533e28841baf74c1068f88b162a5e9b4ea/?ysclid=l8sp31tmlz600671095) this will violate the constitution.

> 1. The territory of the Russian Federation includes the territories of its subjects, internal waters and territorial sea, and the airspace
>    above them. Federal territories may be established on the territory of
>    the Russian Federation in accordance with federal law. The
>    organization of public power in federal territories is established by
>    the specified federal law <*>.
> 2. The Russian Federation has sovereign rights and exercises jurisdiction on the continental shelf and in the exclusive economic
>    zone of the Russian Federation in accordance with the procedure
>    determined by federal law and the norms of international law.
>
> 2.1. The Russian Federation ensures the protection of its sovereignty and territorial integrity. Actions (with the exception of
> delimitation, demarcation, redemarkation of the state border of the
> Russian Federation with neighboring states) aimed at alienating part
> of the territory of the Russian Federation, as well as calls for such
> actions are not allowed <*>.
>
> 3. The borders between the subjects of the Russian Federation may be changed with their mutual consent.

There is priority of Russian law which means, that decisions of interstate bodies adopted on the basis of the provisions of international treaties of the Russian Federation in their interpretation, contrary to the Constitution of the Russian Federation, are not subject to execution in the Russian Federation. So in this context it plays no role for Russia what any international organisation think about it.

So the only posibility would be a pro Western coup similar to 1917 or 1991.

The decision of the constitutional court about DPR can be read [here](http://publication.pravo.gov.ru/Document/View/0001202210020002?ysclid=l8uikt6x1p857088496). It´s about 22 pages long and in russian, so I jus give the translation of the most important part which can be also read in many russian media:

> Recognize the international Agreement between the Russian Federation
> and the Donetsk People's Republic, which has not entered into force,
> on the admission of the Donetsk People's Republic to the Russian
> Federation and the formation of a new subject within the Russian
> Federation in accordance with the Constitution of the Russian
> Federation. This resolution is immediately sent to the President of
> the Russian Federation

And there are similar statements by the court for the other 3 regions.

Also since the question is about parts and not explecitly whole regions, acording to section 2.1 it is posible to give away for example some smal uninhabited areas away as a result of delimitation, demarcation or redemarkation of borders. But for such actions some negotiations about new border are necesary and at the moment [Zelenski has officially refused any negotiations with Russia](https://tass.com/world/1518335?ysclid=l8w04jxqby278051436).

Also as mentioned in the example by @Zeus for example NATO can ivade Russia and instal a new governent which would do everything the West wants including giving teritory to Ukraine.

Comment: Well, historically (and hence under a predecessor constitution) Russia "unannexed" Alaska

Comment: Don't they have provisions for changing the constitution, then?

Comment: You'e discounted the last line of section 2. Since the annexation of eastern Ukraine violates international norms, the Russian government can simply void it as an unconstitutional act. More likely, though, they will simply leave the matter hanging: if/when they are driven out of Ukraine they will (by turns) (a) raise the point as a domestic political issue or (b) studiously ignore the act as a political inconvenience.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley The constitutional court of Russia has yesterday approves acceptance of new regions into Russian Federation, so declaring it unconstitutional would be problematic.

Comment: Problematic for this regime, but not for the next. Courts reverse their rulings fairly often

Comment: Don't the exceptions in section 2.1 explicitly allow Russia to cede territory back to Ukraine, as part of a "redemarkation of the state border of the Russian Federation with neighboring states"?

Comment: @Italian Philosophers It´s not just about loss of face, which in Russia is more problematic then in the West. Acording to Russian constitution and this is what count for russians, not international law, this regions are now part of Russia and if Russia give away that regions how people in other regions can be shure the will not share similar fate.

Comment: I don't see in how far this article of the constitution applies to the accession of new territories to the Russian Federation, only how to deal with territories in the Federation. Couldn't a Russian government that wants to reverse the annexation of the territories in question argue that the annexation was not legal in the first place, and hence the territories were never legally part of the Russian Federation? You say in a comment that the constitutional court of Russia has ruled something along these lines – if so, your answer would benefit greatly from adding details on that ruling.

Comment: @Schmuddi Are you asking me to add the decision by the court?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking, ideally in such a way that it becomes clear what the legal basis of their ruling is. By the way, could you expand your answer so it explains why the exceptions in 2.1 wouldn't apply, as @Ajedi32 asked in their highly-upvoted comment?

Comment: @Schmuddi For delimitation, demarcation or redemarkation some kind of negotiations between the countries is necesary.

Comment: Please add this piece of information to your answer, as it is extremely relevant to your answer. If what you say is true – if changes of demarcation are possible under Article 67 2.1 depending on negotiations between the involved countries – this basically means that it would be fully constitutional if Russia returned the territories to Ukraine as a result of negotiations between the two countries. Currently, your answer suggests that a change of demarcation would be unconstitutional regardless of any negotiations. So, is your comment above incorrect, or does your answer need clarification?

Comment: @Schmuddi I am not a lawyer but giving ups some teritory with people is not how delimitation, demarcation or redemarkation are defined.

Comment: Okay, then I'll have to downvote because I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Schmuddi Can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139625/discussion-between-schmuddi-and-convert).

Comment: 1991 wasn't a coup (or rather, of course, there was a failed one, but it was exactly the opposite, 'anti-Western'). It wasn't a revolution either. It was a _change_, and however you call it, it offers a way. It only requires political will: it would be very easy to declare some parts of the process (most obviously, the referenda)  illegal on the technical grounds, and then the entire process becomes null and void, including the constitutional changes. Somewhat like the (Austrian) anschluss was declared void in 1945: it wasn't 'undone', it (sort of) 'never happened'.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Alaska was sold by the Czar, whose will was more important than any existing laws - there was no constitution at this time. Constitution as a supreme law is characteristic of liberal democracies (although sometimes they keep Monarchs for symbolic reasons - constitutional monarchy) or countries pretending to be liberal democracies. Russia has gone through quite a few constitutions since the fall of the monarchy.

Comment: @Zeus The second coup 1991 was other then the first a political one. The example with Austria and other teritories anexed by Germany is complete diferent, as Germany has sufered a total defeat.

Comment: The question wasn't about _conditions_ when it would happen; it was about the technical (legal) possibilities. Such possibilities exist even without (yet another) change of constitution: the previous change(s) can be declared invalid. It only requires political will, and (as history shows) total defeat is not the only condition for that. Austria provides an _example_ of such mechanism: the whole Nazi system there was dismantled (in legal sense) by voiding the enabling referendum (which, incidentally, also had a 99%+ result).

Comment: @Zeus Austria was ocupied after World War 2, so I still don´t see how that example count.

Comment: Your point is that it's hardly possible because it would violate the constitution, and its change would require occupation or a coup. What I'm saying is that constitution (particularly _Russian_ constitution) is not such a 'hard' obstacle (after all, Russia violates its own constitution daily). There are relatively easy ways to void the changes (or just make new changes, after all, we've seen how easily it could be done). The political will is the primary factor here, and a coup is not the only way. The Q is framed as: _suppose_ there is a will/need, how _technically_ Russia could 'unannex'?

Answer (score 20):

### Constitution changes

The current constitution seems to prohibit this, which implies that after this formal annexation any peace treaty other than a complete Russian victory would require a constitutional amendment to follow due process in Russian legal system. This is not impossible, there are all kinds of historical precedents for countries accepting peace terms which are unconstitutional or being forced to change their constitution. We have also seen constitutional changes pushed in Russia for a specific purpose (e.g. extending president term limits), but that would certainly take time and effort to perform, complicating any negotiations, and essentially meaning that any compromise is now very hard to obtain - the annexation has pushed it towards an 'all or nothing' deal where either Russia keeps all of the annexed territory or has to suffer severe enough loss to be motivated to make concessions that they intentionally made complicated.

Perhaps it is relevant to note that the situation is symmetrical - according to the Ukrainian constitution article 73, any changes to Ukrainian territory must be approved by an all-Ukrainian referendum. Therefore, Zelensky's government does not have the authority to sign a compromise peace treaty which returns some but not all of the currently occupied territories, and the government can not recognize (for example) Crimea as *de jure* Russian land without an approval from a referendum across all of Ukraine.

Answer (score 4):

**War is the continuation of politics by other means** and **Necessity is the mother of invention**.

**IF** Russia loses on the battlefield and **IF** it finds it necessary to conclude a peace treaty with Ukraine, then Ukraine won't care overmuch about Russia's constitutional arrangements.

"Yes, we understand, your constitution doesn't allow for it.  Never mind." makes no sense.

**Whether constitutionally or informally, all nation states have an extreme aversion to loss of territory.  Doesn't mean it doesn't happen, when a state loses a war**.

- France gave up Algeria in 1962, despite Algeria being formally a part of France - [L'ALGÉRIE C'EST LA FRANCE](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/1962/03/20/de-l-algerie-c-est-la-france-a-l-independance-negociee_2346369_1819218.html)- with its own *Departements*.
- Germany lost [Kaliningrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaliningrad#World_War_II) after WW2

etc...

At some point, if mobilization, nukes, or gas blackmail doesn't solve Putin's problems, Russia runs the very real risk of not having armed forces able to challenge Ukraine on Ukrainian territory.  Then all the "constitutional stuff" doesn't matter all that much.

**IF** Ukraine is in a dominant enough position to impose terms then Russia will have no choice but to comply, having failed to enforce its will on the battlefield.  That's the nature of war and unequal treaties: the loser can implicitly loses some of that Westphalian sovereignty - and supremacy of its own laws on its territory - everyone is so fond to talk about.  And that's before we get into how much of a farce "the territories" in question are in this case.

This could be done in several ways:

- Putin losing power and his successor rejecting his annexation.
- Putin finding a technicality with the annexation process, blaming others, and walking it back.  Just like he is blaming MoD for battlefield failures and draft bureaucrats for mobilization errors.
- Arranging for new referendums and recognizing their outcome. Ukraine would probably not go for that and Russia would not want to expose their 90%+ claims for outright fraud.
- A tit for tat, where say Russia gets an internationally-recognized Crimea and returns the rest.
- Amending the constitution.  That seems overkill, since it would seem to open the door for ceding actual parts of Russia in the future.  Unlike everyone else, I see that as the least likely option as it brings genuine long term risk to Russian territorial integrity.
- ...other ways, the end is more relevant than the means...

Putin has shown a great capacity to disregard Russian law.  In the way he has been running elections.  And in the way people have been drafted and sent to die in a non-war.  He can make this work, if he has to, he has that level of control over the state.

Would the Russian people, at that point care overmuch about the pretense that these are actually Russian territories?  And somehow stop Putin from making those concessions?  Really?  This Putin, the one who is pulling all the strings and disregarding Russian laws?

Point is, if the war is lost, then Russia will have to find a way.  The only real problem is that Putin would lose face and may find that risks to his own personal political survival justifies keeping that war going far past any hope for Russia to win.

---

No, halt to combats does *not* need a peace treaty and a peace treaty/ceasefire *may* not address the annexations.

Russia could just be booted out back to its territory and sulk while not engaging in actual combat (no opinion on where Crimea figures in this).

Another possibility is that there is a ceasefire, without Russia actually giving up its claims.

These variations might work, but would sanctions get lifted sufficiently to make this viable long term for Russia?

**IF the war is lost, then Russia will just have to suck it up and make adjustments, just like other countries have had to do when losing wars.**  If the war is not conclusively lost then Russia has limited reasons to worry about un-annexation, except if it wants to be a good neighbor.

p.s. this is all predicated on the war being conclusively won by Ukraine.  Which is a bit early to call though on current extrapolation Russia is losing, big time.

p.p.s.  and the reverse equally applies to Ukraine, should they lose big time - their own constitutional prohibitions about territory cessions will have to be worked around.

Comment: *IF Russia loses on the battlefield and it finds it necessary to conclude a peace treaty with Ukraine* - ending of a war doesn't imply/require signing a peace treaty. *Peace treaty* regulates relations between countries, and there are many examples of countries not engaging in a war despite an absence of a formal peace agreement. Colloquial use of *peace* as *absence of war* is misleading in this respect.

Comment: @RogerVadim True, but that's already mentioned several times in my post.  Editing once again to reinforce this.  However... sanctions may also very well be hard to lift unless Russia stops claiming as its own Ukrainian territory that Ukraine is not willing to negotiate about.  Anyway, this is more "where there is a will there is a way", not so much that Russia *will* have to do it.

Comment: Algeria 1962 is a good example, but I think Kaliningrad 1945 is not : it was not detached from Germany the IIIrd Reich legal system nor even the Weimar Constitution, but when those juridictions had disappeared.

Comment: @Evargalo seems covered [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_changes_of_Poland_immediately_after_World_War_II).  Kalingrad was Danzig and there were other cessions too.  But the idea is that unhappy changes sometime come to losers and that their internal legal system has little traction.

Answer (score 3):

A constitutional change as such only seems like a high barrier because of the notion that it is difficult to change the constitution.  As it happens, the barrier to changing the constitution in the Russian Federation is very low.

- It doesn't require any referendum.
- It requires 2/3rds supermajority of the lower house of the federal parliament and 3/4th of the upper house.
- ratification by 2/3rds of the regional legislatures.

This all may seem like a difficult hurdle to pass, but it's not.

- Putin's party has a lock on the parliament.
- And a [2020 law](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2000-jul-20-mn-55849-story.html) has given the President the power to dismiss regional governors and legislators. So the regional legislators can be forced to ratify "or else."
- The Russian government owns controlling interest (>50%) of [Gazprom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazprom), the largest producer of gas and oil in Russia and the largest private bank in Russia.  This makes Russia effectively a corporate state with the President of Russia controlling access to the top positions in Gazprom.  So one way or another, he has control over the parliament's access to the food chain.

It's also not clear if the votes even serve any function other than an advisory one because any amendments only take force after a President signs an executive order amending the constitution.  In fact, after Ukraine took back Lyman, Putin [signed an executive order excluding Lyman from the Russian Federation](https://twitter.com/olliecarroll/status/1576273418710048768).

Comment: Counterpoint: Putin is the one who pushed *for* the change in the Russian constitution that makes it illegal to cede any territory. It was a propaganda move for him, declaring his  intent to rebuild the Great Russian Empire and reclaim the wayward soviets, will they or nil they. Amending the constitution again to take it back would be an admission of *complete* failure, and his strongman self-image can't survive that.

Comment: @Shadur what his image would or wouldn't survive is off topic for this site.  That's an opinion.  We deal with what's known to be a fact.  If there is a mechanism for a government to perform a certain function, then, for the purposes of what this site covers, it's possible.

Comment: Suggesting that image and perception don't matter in politics is *beyond* absurd. That goes triple for the type of authoritarian strongman politics that Putin has been playing for the past decade. He *cannot* admit to having been wrong, and he'll let Russia  - and if need be the rest of the world - burn first. Look at history -- tyrants rarely go quietly, if ever.

Comment: @Shadur the topics on this site are more narrow than its name suggests.  It's not anything that has to do with "politics."  It's formation and functioning of governments and governmental institutions as can be verified by independent sources.  While some opinions maybe relevant to the larger topic of politics, they are nonetheless off topic for the site if they cannot be independently verified.

Answer (score 0):

If the opposing political party comes to power, they can easily do. The referendums are seen by the most of the world as not having legal power.

Here is a good comment from another answer to cite:

> Around about ~600,000 ethnic Russians live in the City of New York. Russia declares that it has annexed the City of New York to protect the interests of those Russians, naming it the New York oblast. Once annexed, the Russian government can never un-annex that territory? Interesting.

This may be seen as "unconstitutional" from inside the current Russian legal framework, who cares. It is always possible to say that current decisions were made by authoritarian government that also influenced the constitutional law court so the decisions so are all void.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**

This question is part of a calculated disinformation campaign of Russia. The Hungarian media has just covered it today: https://444.hu/2022/10/08/racz-andras-moszkva-elhitetne-hogy-az-annexiok-utan-nincs-visszaut-ukrajna-es-a-nyugat-lehivja-az-orosz-bloffot

---

Russia is not a country operating under the guiding principle of the law; there is merely the rule of the ruler in guise of law. It doesn’t matter what the formal provisions of “law” say because the ruler will have its minions formally change it as the ruler seems necessary hence the question cannot be answered as a matter of *Russian* law. It can be answered as a matter of reasonable corroboration: Putin will have to accept it and that’s what he will do.

It can be, however, answered as a matter of *international* law: Nothing happened here other than genocide, on about six different categories of it, and war crimes. There is no “annexion” only in public discourse; an annexion is complete when the international community unanimously acknowledges it ***except*** if an international court declares that the anexion occurred in substantial violation of international law therefor it is null and void, and merely a matter of the status quo. ECtHR was a step quicker to make a ruling on war crimes before Russia could have left the European Council and relieve Russia from the jurisdiction of the European Court of Human Rights, hence that is the matter of law.

The annexion will never be lawful, and in with almost certainty, a formal “peace treaty” of Ukraine could be challenged by those with standing (like those having to lose their Ukrainian citizenship).

So understand: There will never be a lawful situation where Russia, oh poor Russia, won’t be able to stop because its “law” says so. The ECtHR’s decision is the final decisional law.

TL;DR

Just because Russia’s mouth is puppeted by its leader doesn’t mean it has any legal force. This question poses as it would be a reasonable possibility that the army could not, but had to proceed despite the administrations and its rulers decision to stop the war. The ruler of Russia can have any formal provisions of “law” and “constitution” changed so informally it is a matter of decree. That will be subject of whatever become necessary.

Comment: You can dislike this answer all you want. The fact is Russia already wrote the 4 Ukrainian counties in its formal “constitution”. That’s how big of a deal it is for Putin to have something included in that toilet paper. And that’s precisely how much effort it’s going to take when it will take it out of it.